# Partial Lookup Lists

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to limit the amount of data coming across when implementing [Lookup Lists](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/lookup-lists) in Breeze.JS. The Lookup Lists sample uses queries that results in full objects but I would like to project the entities to fewer properties (e.g. primary key, foreign keys, and a descriptor property) and still have Breeze.JS recognize the entity type on the client. I know how to do the projections from the client to get partials but how would I do that with Lookup Lists (either from the client or the server Web API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might satisfy your intentions with a custom `JsonResultsAdapter`.

You're probably wondering "*What is a `JsonResultsAdapter`?*"

That's what breeze uses to interpret the JSON arriving from the server. You can [read about here](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/mapping-json-entities) and [here](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/JsonResultsAdapter.html).

Perhaps more helpful is to look at [the adapter in the Web API dataservice](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/b00_breeze.dataService.webApi.js#L76) and at [the example adapter from the "Edmumds" sample](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/no-server/edmunds/app/jsonResultsAdapter.js).

> The Edmunds sample demonstrates translating a JSON source that you don't control into breeze entities.

In this case, your `JsonResultsAdapter` would look at each node of JSON and say "*this is a Foo, this is a Bar, and that one is a Baz*". Accordingly, for each of these nodes it would  `return { entityType: "Foo"  }`, `return { entityType: "Bar"  }`, and  `return { entityType: "Baz"  }`

Now breeze knows what to do and creates corresponding entities out of the Lookups payload.

Remember to mark these entities as partial, in the same way you would if you had made a projection query that targeted a single entity type.

Fortunately, the Lookups query returns the container object that holds the Foo, Bar, and Baz collections. So you can iterate over these and mark them partial right there in the query success callback.

Once you wrap your head around THAT ... you'll want to know how to put your custom `JsonResultsAdapter` to work in the Lookups query ... and ONLY in the Lookups query.

You can enlist that `JsonResultsAdapter` exclusively for your Lookups query [with a `using` clause](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_using).

Here's an example:

```
var jsa = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({
    name: 'myLookupsJsa',
    visitNode:      function() {...}
});

query = query.using(jsa);
```

Is this overkill? Would you be better off making three trips?

Only you will know. I would like to hear from you when you try it ... and give us your suggestions on how we might make this easier in a general way.

Answer (score 0):

In the [lookup lists example](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/lookup-lists) the controller action looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Lookups() // returns an object, not an IQueryable
{
    var regions = _contextProvider.Context.Regions;
    var territories = _contextProvider.Context.Territories;
    var categories = _contextProvider.Context.Categories;

    return new {regions, territories, categories};
}
```

You could reduce the footprint using a server-side projection like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Lookups() // returns an object, not an IQueryable
{
    var regions = _contextProvider.Context.Regions
        .Select(x => new { id = x.RegionId, name = x.RegionName });
    var territories = _contextProvider.Context.Territories
        .Select(x => new { id = x.TerritoryId, name = x.TerritoryName });
    var categories = _contextProvider.Context.Categories
        .Select(x => new { id = x.CategoryId, name = x.CategoryName });

    return new {regions, territories, categories};
}
```

This approach does not answer this part of your question:

> and still have Breeze.JS recognize the entity type on the client

Not sure what the solution or use case is for this piece.

Comment: Thanks! But I already tried that. It's really the second part of the question that has me stumped. I could select partials of each of these from the client but I want to keep the number of calls to a minimum (which is the purpose of the Lookup List functionality). It would be nice if there were a server-side cast for the Linq projection so that Breeze would serialize the anonymous type as an Entity type. Or a different client-side method of calling for the Lookup List where I could specify the select projection and toType for each list so that Breeze can cache the partials appropriately.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean:  you want to load a subset of the entity's properties from the server and convert these minimal POJO objects to a full-on breeze entities on the client.  Is that correct?